# Android Java | InflateException error inflating class when I call setContentView()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am new to Android. I am trying to make a simple app that creates a Pie Chart.

I have 2 activities, one is MainActivity and the other is PieChart, both extending Activity, and I have a MyView class which extends View.

In the MainActivity I have a button which is bound to a onClick event (set as a android:onClick="createPieChart" Button XML attribute) and when I click on it a function called 'creaTorta()' should change the activity and create the pie chart.

here is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View vista;

    public void creaPieChart(View myView){
       Intent viewPieChart = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), PieChart.class);
       startActivity(viewPieChart);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       vista= (View)findViewById(R.id.viewtorta1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the PieChart activity:

```
 public class PieChart extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Log.d("Point", "Here I am!");

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_la_torta);
    Log.d("Point", "Here I am again!");

   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.la_torta, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

And here is the MyView.java:

```
public class MyView extends View {
  private float cx=0,cy=0;
  private RectF r = new RectF(100,100,430,430);
  private float valori[] = {10,20,10,30,25,5};
      private Paint p,ct;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    p=new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    ct=new Paint();
    ct.setAntiAlias(true);
}

   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
      float degStart=0,x,y;
      int i=0;
      ct.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
      for (float count : valori){
        float degVal=(float) (count*3.6);
        p.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 125, 255-i));
        x=(float)(Math.cos((((degStart-90))*Math.PI)/180)*200)+265 ;
        y=(float)(Math.sin((((degStart-90))*Math.PI)/180)*200)+265;



        canvas.drawArc(r, degStart-90 , degVal, true, p);

        canvas.drawText(""+degVal, x  ,y , ct);

        degStart+=degVal;
        i+=50;
    }
  } 

}
```

When I click on the button I get the following error: 
FATAL EXCEPTION main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo()
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file Line #18: Error Inflating class it.adriano.piechart.MyView

EDIT: Here is the activity_la_torta.xml file. The app crashes when I call the setContentView(R.layout.activity_la_torta) in the PieChart onCreate();

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/chiuditorta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<it.adriano.unatorta.MyView
    android:id="@+id/myView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewtorta1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the full stack trace (sorry for the indentation, if there's a way to post in a better way, please tell me):

```
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189): 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.adriano.unatorta/it.adriano.unatorta.LaTorta}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: 
Error inflating class it.adriano.unatorta.MyView
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189): 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class it.adriano.unatorta.MyView
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at it.adriano.unatorta.LaTorta.onCreate(LaTorta.java:21)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     ... 11 more
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
03-14 13:41:52.009: E/AndroidRuntime(2189):     ... 22 more
```

How can I resolve. I do not understand why it doesn't start the startActivity(viewPieChart); properly. What am I messing?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: what is your layout xml?

Comment: Please post full stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

Your `MyView` class does not have the `MyView(Context, AttributeSet)` constructor overload required for views inflated from XML.

For example, change your current constructor

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    p=new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    ct=new Paint();
    ct.setAntiAlias(true);
}
```

to the two required constructor overloads with shared init function:

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    p=new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    ct=new Paint();
    ct.setAntiAlias(true);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I am newbie in android, what should I do? Change the constructor?

Comment: @user3019105 Updated with concrete example

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Could you please tell me why it didn't work before? Why there's another constructor with AttributeSet attrs?

Comment: The XML attributes defined in XML are passed to the view and its superclasses in the `AttributeSet` object.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you say. Could you please make an example?